# SQL max n versions for each week of each year

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a data table with [YEAR], [WEEKNO], [VERSIONNO] cols (and others).

I want to output the whole row (each column) of the latest n number of VERSIONNO's for each WEEKNO in each YEAR.

What's the best way to do it in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `max(versionno) group by year,weakno`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year, weekno order by versionno desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= n    -- Your value goes here
```

`row_number()` is ANSI-standard functionality supported by most databases.